# Renpy showing default avatar when not instructed

Tags: python, renpy

I have a problem I am making a visual novel in `renpy` but for some reason it throws out the default avatar at some of my scenes.

I am not going for avatars on background images, instead I want the whole game to be a series of images.

Is it maybe not possible to do it this way. How do I fix it? Please help.

```
# The game starts here.

label start:

    # Show a background. This uses a placeholder by default, but you can
    # add a file (named either "bg room.png" or "bg room.jpg") to the
    # images directory to show it.

 

    # This shows a character sprite. A placeholder is used, but you can
    # replace it by adding a file named "eileen happy.png" to the images
    # directory.

    show room
    
   
    # These display lines of dialogue.

    "Scott strolled through the early morning streets, having completed his night shift as a security guard. All he desired was some rest, as he faced another monotonous night ahead. Despite finding the job incredibly dull, he had to maintain a low profile, being a hunted man."
     
    "For the past four years, Scott had been on the run, pursued by dangerous individuals. Uncertain of his fate, he wondered whether capture would mean life or death at the hands of those searching for him."


    "Suddenly, a tingling sensation washed over him, signalling that someone was tailing him. Could it be them pursuing him? "
    


    # This ends the game.

   
   
    show allyway
   
   
    "Opting to take a shortcut through an alleyway, he decided to navigate through the graveyard and set a trap. It was crucial to confirm the identity of his pursuer, considering it might just be a figment of his imagination. "

    show graveyard

    

    "Reaching the graveyard entrance, the nagging feeling persisted. Convinced it was not a product of his imagination, he cut a diagonal path through the graveyard and then cast a glamour, rendering himself nearly invisible until whoever was trailing him was on top of him."


    show josua

    "You can dispel the glamour, Scott, Joshua, a necromancer, stated confidently"
    "He heard soft footstep coming from his left"
    show sa005

    "Glancing to his left, he saw someone approaching, a bare naked woman converting light into mana."
    

    show scott

    "Release me, and I won't cause you harm, Scott compelled himself to project confidence despite the rapid beating of his heart. Joshua responded with a malicious, hearty laugh, In a graveyard, facing two necromancers, you're in no position to make demands."

    show graveyard2

    "Scott swiftly turned and sprinted, incorporating a touch of magic to boost your muscular strength, rapidly crossing the graveyard towards the exit. As you ran, you maximized the conversion of light into energy."

    show undead

    "As you approached the exit, undead creatures began emerging from their graves all around you. Before reaching the exit, the undead strategically positioned themselves, forming a blockade in your path"

    "With minimal mana remaining, you could feel Joshua and Sandra positioned behind you, radiating powerful energy and summoning additional undead. Despite your limited resources, you weren't without defence. You directed a forceful wave towards the undead, creating a path."

    show third mage

    "However, as you sprinted forward, a third person moved to obstruct your way.  Great you thought, anticipating yet another obstacle."

    "This individual was a stranger to you, and you did not know his potential abilities."

    show defeated

    "As you began converting more light into mana, a powerful force knocked you to the ground. Despite your attempts to rise, an unseen force kept you pinned. Your efforts to employ magic proved futile; it wouldn't respond to your commands. You realized it was the end." 

    return
```

Answer (score 0):

All your `show` commands just show a new picture on top of whatever else was shown before. When you put a new background image up, it will not show up behind the character, but in front of it. The character sprites are essentially hidden behind your background sprites in one large pile of sprites.

The easiest solution to this is to rename your background images to something like `bg room.jpg`, `bg allyway.jpg` and show them using `show bg room` and `show bg allyway` respectively. This way whatever background you had before will be just replaced with the new one, keeping the order.

Docs: https://www.renpy.org/doc/html/displaying_images.html